# How to add a slide-up view with multiple buttons? Is there any ready-to-use component in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add to my application a new view with buttons for sharing content or saving it to disk. I know how to do sharing itself (save, email), but I wonder if this layer should be created as frame or there is any ready-to-use class displaying modal ![alt text][1]layer for half screen?

I prefer to ask before doing it manually. I'm not sure if frame is only method of displaying this for half screen size, or maybe I should display transparent layer and add only non-transparent rect with buttons for half screen?

I'm not able to add pictures yet, so I put example on my website: http://iphone.orpi.pl/?p=31

Comment: I can't believe I had to read all the way to the last paragraph before realizing this is asking about the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the picture on your link, it's clear you're talking about an **Action Sheet**.

This is how you initialise & display one:

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"My Title"
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
destructiveButtonTitle:@"Go"
otherButtonTitles:@"Remind me Later",nil];
```

If you want to track clicks on the button, you must set the delegate (as above), and the delegate must conform to the `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol (set in the h file).

The event that you then override for handling the button taps is

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
                            clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    //code
}
```

Comment: thank you. Hint for others - it is described in iPhones Human Interface Guidelines

Answer (score 0):

I think, that one or two more lines may be helpful for other people to display sheet:

```
[sheet showInView:self.view];
[sheet release];
```

and one more hint to change astionsheet style

popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;